# Django SELECT (1) AS [a] FROM [my_table] WHERE ([my_table].[id] = ? AND NOT ([my_table].[id] = ? )) (1, 1)

Tags: django, orm

Why is Django executing statements such as this:

```
SELECT (1) AS [a] FROM [my_table] 
WHERE ([my_table].[id] = ?  
AND NOT ([my_table].[id] = ? )) (1, 1)
```

This happens when calling is_valid() on a formset created the following way:

```
MyFormSet = modelformset_factory(Table, fields=['my_field'], extra=0)
my_form_set = MyFormSet(request.POST,
                        queryset=Table.objects.all())
```

where Table and MyForm are as simple as, say:

```
class Table(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Table
```

Hint: I looked at the call stack and the code responsible for it (in django/forms/models.py) is below:

```
def _perform_unique_checks(self, unique_checks):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    bad_fields = set()
    form_errors = []

    for unique_check in unique_checks:
        # Try to look up an existing object with the same values as this
        # object's values for all the unique field.

        lookup_kwargs = {}
        for field_name in unique_check:
            lookup_value = self.cleaned_data[field_name]
            # ModelChoiceField will return an object instance rather than
            # a raw primary key value, so convert it to a pk value before
            # using it in a lookup.
            if isinstance(self.fields[field_name], ModelChoiceField):
                lookup_value =  lookup_value.pk
            lookup_kwargs[str(field_name)] = lookup_value

        qs = self.instance.__class__._default_manager.filter(**lookup_kwargs)

        # Exclude the current object from the query if we are editing an
        # instance (as opposed to creating a new one)
        if self.instance.pk is not None:
            qs = qs.exclude(pk=self.instance.pk)
```

Basically the pk is both included for the uniqueness check and excluded.  Looks like Django can be smarter and avoid such inefficiency.

Comment: You may need to post your code for people to look at.

Comment: To second David's comment, we'll need to see what Django queryset was used to generate this SQL before we can comment.

Comment: Jarret, I was hoping that the above will ring the bell.  If noone answers soon I'll provide more context.

Comment: Is this a quiz show or something? Of course you'll have to post more info to get any meaningful answer.

Comment: I just edited this.  I still think, however, that anyone who has seen this before would have recognized the symptom without further code samples or explanation.  Perhaps people are not looking under the hood that much.

Comment: @kmt did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this has been fixed already in trunk (by adding new functionality that also fixes this particular problem)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't looked at it in detail, but I think you are right that Django could shortcut this query. Please file a ticket at http://code.djangoproject.com/.

Comment: Do you think this was solved meanwhile?